# Upgrade To PHP 8.1 Prevented By WordPress CiviCRM Plugin

Tags: wordpress, php8

WordPress v6.4.2 CiviCRM v5.68.0

My hosting provider stated, "The issue with [my website] is caused due to the plugin civicrm. It seems that the version of the plugin is not fully compatible with PHP 8.1."

So, I keep being told to update to PHP 8.1 but cannot. What do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed my acceptance of my answer of changing the {0} to [0] because I fear it might misguide others. The correct answer is a combination of @Coleman statement of updating the extension which is ALWAYS the proper way, if available, and that @bgm has updated the numerical hierarchy in order to accomplish this. I thank both parties for their time and effort and simply want the record to reflect their tireless efforts!

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM v5.68.0 *is* fully compatible with PHP 8.1.

However, some extensions you may be using for CiviCRM might not be. You should ask your hosting provider for clarification about the specific incompatibility they are referring to.

Comment: This was the specific error: [13-Dec-2023 11:52:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.angularprofiles/angularprofiles.civix.php on line 246

Comment: Glad you solved the mystery.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't see a notification in CiviCRM that a new version of AngularProfiles is available. It's been out for the past 6 weeks and solves the PHP8 problem.

Comment: Angular Profiles
A Utility extension that provides Profile support to AngularJS pages Enabled 4.7.31-1.1.2

Comment: Changed {0} to [0] in line 246 and solved everything. Got the idea from here: https://civicrm.org/blog/bgm/php-8-support-civicrm-extensions.

Comment: ... or you could have simply upgraded. As I said, [the latest release](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/angularprofiles/-/releases/1.2.4) solves the php8 issue.

Comment: So, to be real clear here, I didn't have an option to upgrade. I suppose I could have manually downloaded the extension, gone into cPanel, etc. but that is kinda counter productive as the system should have advised it needed to be upgraded.

Comment: That's very strange. I see that [the latest version is released](https://civicrm.org/extensions/angular-profile-utilities) and available for automatic download.

Comment: Screenshot below. Run my own cloud server so not like a trash, shared setup. Willing to run any tests if you think it would help determine for others or Core, just give me a holler. Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/ldhc6wE

Comment: I'd guess that's due to the oddball way those versions got numbered. You've got version `5.23-1.2.2` but the latest release is `1.2.4`... however the computer would think that it's not an update because 5 is greater than 1.

Comment: @PaulWilliams Can you check if your CiviCRM install now displays an available upgrade for version 6.2.4? I bumped the version number to fix the issue (looks like there are many many people still running the old version, we need to make sure they upgrade asap). Click "Refresh" to make sure it updates the feed of available extensions.

Comment: That is affirmative. Seamlessly updated. Appreciate all you folks do! Screenshot attached. https://imgur.com/a/wV6HaHk

Answer (score 0):

Changed {0} to [0] in line 246 and solved everything. Got the idea from here: civicrm.org/blog/bgm/php-8-support-civicrm-extensions